# How to go to next line if string width is long in swift

Tags: ios, swift, epson

I am Currently working on Receipt.
in receipt I have three labels. Product quantity,product name and product price.
when I product name is big than it should go to next line

I am using EPSON Printer to Print data.

I am able to do Print.but when product name is big than I am getting receipt alignment issue  like this image

[image: Print Image]

but I want to receipt like this

[image]

aligmnet issues I get when product name is big.to overcome this issue I think I should use range according to length of string

I am using this code

```
 pName = "Chicken"
 if pName.characters.count > 13       {
        var x = (pName as NSString).substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, 13))
            x = x.stringByAppendingFormat("%@                                 ", (pName as NSString).substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(13, pName.characters.count - 13)))
             x = x.stringByAppendingFormat("%@                                 ", (pName as NSString).substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(13,26)))
            textData.appendString(x)
        }
```

but I am not getting proper alignment.
can you help me to help how to make aligmemnt proper.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: Do you have to "layout" your text using spaces?

Comment: @d.felber Yes.i want to layout text